# Let's Encrypt certbot-auto setuptools version error when run from cron

Tags: cron, python, lets-encrypt, dependencies, certbot

CentOS 6, certbot 0.16.0. When I run it manually as root (not by sudo) everything works. When I setup /etc/crontab to run it automatically it returns an error:

```
Error: couldn't get currently installed version for //.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt: 
//.local/share/letsencrypt/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/cryptography/__init__.py:26: DeprecationWarning: Python 2.6 is no longer supported by the   Python core team, please upgrade your Python. A future version of cryptography will drop support for Python 2.6
  DeprecationWarning
An unexpected error occurred:
ContextualVersionConflict: (setuptools 0.9.8 (/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=1.0'), set(['certbot']))
Please see the logfile '/tmp/tmp5jOtY3' for more details.`
```

cat /tmp/tmp5jOtY3

```
2017-07-31 11:37:02,325:DEBUG:certbot.log:Exiting abnormally:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "//.local/share/letsencrypt/bin/letsencrypt", line 11, in <module>
sys.exit(main())
  File "//.local/share/letsencrypt/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/certbot/main.py", line 723, in main
plugins = plugins_disco.PluginsRegistry.find_all()
  File "//.local/share/letsencrypt/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 203, in find_all
plugin_ep = PluginEntryPoint(entry_point)
  File "//.local/share/letsencrypt/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/certbot/plugins/disco.py", line 50, in __init__
self.plugin_cls = entry_point.load()
  File "//.local/share/letsencrypt/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2201, in load
self.require(*args, **kwargs)
  File "//.local/share/letsencrypt/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2218, in require
items = working_set.resolve(reqs, env, installer)
  File "//.local/share/letsencrypt/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 835, in resolve
raise VersionConflict(dist, req).with_context(dependent_req)
ContextualVersionConflict: (setuptools 0.9.8 (/.local/share/letsencrypt/lib/python2.6/site-packages), Requirement.parse('setuptools>=1.0'), set(['certbot']))
```

cat /etc/crontab

```
SHELL=/bin/bash
PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
MAILTO=root
HOME=/

27  18  *  *  * root /opt/certbot-auto renew --quiet --no-self-upgrade
```

I tried Let's Encrypt community and found someone having this exact problem, but the only help offered was migration to bash script. I would prefer to fix the official script instead.

[Let's Encrypt forum post](https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/problem-renewing-certs-from-cron-job/38464/12)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the issue:

```
HOME=/
```

To fix it HOME variable with /root value needs to be passed to the script:

```
env HOME=/root /path/to/certbot-auto
```

Comment: This can break other entries in your crontab if they aren't all running as root. You'll see an 'ERROR chdir failed (/root/): Permission denied" message in /var/log/cron on centos at least

Comment: To @xref's point, if you do have other cron entries that aren't running as root, you're better off setting the path just for certbot by changing the command to `env PATH=/root /opt/certbot-auto`.

Comment: @ScottSB Almost... HOME, not PATH: `env HOME=/root /path/to/certbot-auto`

Comment: Ah, yes, good point. :-)